# How do you split merged date value

Tags: php

Supose like this:

> $two_dates=$_GET['fromto'];
>
> echo $two_dates;
>
> output is: '2015-05-05 - 2015-06-06';

I need somehow to brake this into this:

> $date1='2015-05-05';
>
> $date2='2015-06-06';

How do you split it ?

Comment: What did a Google search reveal?

Comment: http://php.net/explode

Comment: What have you tried? It is really basic php, i can't believe you didn't find something in internet to help you... try before post here please.

Comment: @olibiaz: Put answers as an answer not comment.

Comment: Explode was the solution @Oisin, didnt thinking..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use explode to do that:

```
list($date1, $date2) = explode(" - ", '2015-05-05 - 2015-06-06');
```

see: http://php.net/manual/fr/function.explode.php